From where does Pycharm download remote resource?
I set up a remote interpreter on Linux for Pycharm. It downloads pre-build index (I guess, not sure) to a local folder /home/user/AppData/local/JetBrain/PycharmVersion/remote_sources. The problem is that it downloads a folder containing many datasets. Even after setting up a new project, it downloads all the old dataset from the folder. How to avoid downloading the data folder?

Is the data-folder part of one of your dependencies? Or is it something in your project?

pre-build-index sounds like it's getting something from pip (or it's alternatives like conda)

Data folder was under my old project. I guess Pycharm indexed it at that time and uploaded it somewhere and keep downloading it, event with a new project.

'uploaded it somewhere'? Pycharm certainly doesn't upload your local files to any server, otherwise most corporations would ban the product. There must be something else going on. Describe your projects setup and where that data is. Is the data part of a module installed on the interpreter you use for both projects? Are you using virtual environments?
